Issue with Password Reset Link Across Different Browsers in Keycloak
I'm encountering an issue with the password reset functionality in Keycloak when using different browsers. Here are the details:

When I request a password reset link using Microsoft Edge and open the link in Edge, everything works fine, and I'm able to reset my password without any issues.
However, when I request a password reset link using Google Chrome and then open the link in Edge, I'm unable to reset my password.

Has anyone else experienced this issue? Are there any known solutions or configurations in Keycloak that could help resolve this cross-browser compatibility problem?
Steps to reproduce
Requested a password reset link using Microsoft Edge.
Opened the password reset link in Edge and successfully reset my password.
Requested a password reset link using Google Chrome.
Opened the password reset link in Edge, but was unable to reset my password.
I expected to be able to reset my password successfully regardless of the browser used to request the password reset link. Specifically, I expected the password reset process to work seamlessly when requesting the link in Chrome and opening it in Edge, just as it does when both steps are performed in Edge.

"...but was unable to reset my password." <-- This is not an adequate problem description. Please state exactly what differs between Edge and Chrome and exactly what "unable" means - and do you see any server-side error? Client-side error? Cookie issue? Etc?
